# how to save the content of a uitextview to a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` and when I press a 'Save' button I would like that the `text` will get added to a row in my `UITableView`. I've set up the table view already. I'd also like to get to the `UITextView` when selecting one on the table view.

Comment: how are you populating the table view? how is that data that you use saved? what have you tried? can you show that code? (p.s. welcome to SO, we just need more info before we can help)

Comment: @wain I am fairly new to Objective - C so I haven't tried much yet ... I just would need a hint.

Comment: How far are you? You can get the text from the view? And you say you have a table view - is it displaying anything (was it created as part of the app template for you)?

Comment: I think you are confused about saving content and loading content to a table. Tables do not save their content by default they are just containers (views) helping to present data. In other words you first need to save the contents from the text field and than you would load that content to a table. To save there are a few different ways to do it, Core Data, NSUserDefaults, pLists etc.

Once you successfully save the data using one of the methods mentioned above you can read/load it to a UITableView. Do you just want to load the contents from the text field to the table without saving it?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to add the data to your data source. Depending on how your table is set up that might just entail adding an extra string to an array, if you edit your question with more detail I can be more specific here.

Next you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on your table view, changing the value of the index path depending on where you've added the new data.

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

The table view will take care of the rest, it will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to make the new table cell (using the data you just added to the data source) and will even animate it into position for you.

For the second part of your question, you'll need to implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and in there get the appropriate string from your data source based on the selected row, and set the text view accordingly. Something like

```
textView.text = myDataSourceArray[indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic, but this example should do the trick. 
https://cloud.jakota.de/public.php?service=files&t=922500d0732da5ce3cc71b6fdf517a83